# Function template overloading and ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The code is taken from [Partial template function specialization with enable_if: make default implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585504/partial-template-function-specialization-with-enable-if-make-default-implementa) . I was expecting the call to `dummy(5)` to be ambiguous between the "Generic" and the "Integral" overloads as `T` is deduced as `int` in both cases. The second parameter resolves to `void` in both cases. Aren't they equally "ranked" in the call to `dummy(5)` ? How does the compiler choose the "Generic" version ?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
void dummy(T t)
{
  std::cout << "Generic: " << t << std::endl;
}


template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
void dummy(T t)
{
  std::cout << "Integral: " << t << std::endl;
}


template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
void dummy(T t)
{
  std::cout << "Floating point: " << t << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  dummy(5); // Print "Generic: 5"
  dummy(5.); // Print "Generic: 5"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Integral" overload can't be called because the 2nd template argument can't be inferred. (Note that `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type` is trying to decalre a non-type template parameter with type `void` when `T` is integer type, which is invalid.)

If you change the type to pointer (as non-type template parameter) and provide a default argument for it (like the "Generic" overload, which is declaring type template parameter with default argument `void`) then the calling would be ambiguous.

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void dummy(T t)
{
  std::cout << "Integral: " << t << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @sdp They're not the same. `typename Enable = void` is declaring a type template parameter with default argument `void`. `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type` is trying to decalre a non-type template parameter with type `void` when `T` is integer type, which is invalid.

Comment: @sdp Try to remove the "Generic" overload, you'll see the "Integral" overload won't be called at all.